# Can I become a messianic Jew

Tags: holidays, pagan

I am a Christian....however I no longer believe in many of the celebrations....
Christmas....Easter.....these are indeed pagan holidays and I think even if the person does not pay tribute to Nimrod nor Ishtar/Easter openly the foundation of the worship of both are still present in these holiest of celebrations.  I'll go so far as to say that the deception runs throughout today's modern Christian church by leaders who are complicit in the deception at best just plain ignorant.
What should I do?  I imagine Messianic Jews know and practice the feasts set forth by Yahweh and know too that pagan practice runs throughout the Christian Church.

Comment: I studied Messianic Judaism for similar reasons you've mentioned.  I'd suggest finding a local Messianic Judaism group and ask them - From my experience, they're very welcoming.

Comment: You could become a Jehovah's Witness they celebrate no holidays  only observe the lords evening  meal once a year to commemorate the death of Jesus. Festivals held by Jews prior to Jesus new covenant are now obsolete as well.

Comment: Seventh-day Adventists also.

Comment: Seventh-day Adventists [don't celebrate the Jewish feasts](http://www.amazingfacts.org/media-library/book/e/27/t/feast-days-and-sabbaths) as we believe that they were fulfilled by Jesus Christ. We do celebrate some [holidays such as Christmas](http://www.amazingfacts.org/news-and-features/af-blog/article/id/10955/t/should-we-celebrate-christmas),  nevertheless we use this time to give to the poor and remember the birth of Jesus, though we fully acknowledge that Jesus was not born on December 24.  Look into it, I think you will find it Biblical and helpful.